# How do i make a Google BQ Merge Statement work?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to work an SQL statement that Copies the Entire content of a Source Table into the Destination Table using the Merge statement. The flow i'm trying to work on is; check if a row of data from the Source Table exists on the Destination Table, if it does Do Nothing and if it doesn't then insert that row of data into the Source Table.

So this is the code i have currently but it doesnt work like it should.

```
MERGE `myProject.myDataset.test_destination` T
USING `myProject.myDatatset.test_source` S
ON (T.department = S.department AND
   T.category = S.category AND
   T.subcategory = S.subcategory
   T.country = S.country AND
   T.state = S.state AND
   T.county = S.county AND 
   T.date = S.date)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ROW
```

The issue when i run this query is i tend to have more data on the Destination than the Source. which shouldn't be the case(they should be the same).

Oh yes i forgot to add. The Table doesn't have a unique field as primary key. We use Compound Fields to uniquely identify each row of data..

I will appreciate any form of help..

Comment: You should investigate your data.  If I had to speculate, I would guess `NULL` values are involved.

Comment: Yes NULL values are involved.. most at the Subcategory Level..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be `NULL` values.  If so, you can try modifying the conditions to

```
( (T.department = S.department OR t.department IS NULL and S.department IS NULL) AND
  (T.category = S.category OR t.category IS NULL and S.category IS NULL) AND
  . . .
)
```

However, BQ may not like those conditions.  In that case, use `COALESCE()`.  You have to use a type appropriate for the column -- and one that doesn't interfere with the column value, but:

```
( COALESCE(T.department, '<null>') = COALESCE(S.department, '<null>') AND
  . . .
)
```

Or convert to JSON:

```
( to_json_string(T.department, t.category, . . .) = 
  to_json_string(S.department, S.category, . . .)
)
```

Comment: Awesome.. i will work on this and get back at you

Comment: This works.. Thanks alot.. i used the first suggestion which uses the *IS NULL* statement.. I will refactor it to use COALESCE.. 
Once again thanks

Comment: is there anyway i can add a WHERE Clause to this Query..having a statement like WHERE a department on the Source Table is equal to something 

like department = "FOOTBALL"

Comment: @samlexxy . . . `MERGE` doesn't accept an overall `WHERE` clause.  However, you can include filters in the match conditions, which should be sufficieint.

Comment: is there anyway i can include a condition that deletes any duplicate on the destination table.. like 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND (having COUNT(*) > 1) THEN
   DELETE

Comment: or a way to modify the Query so it doesnt insert Duplicates to Destination Table or delete the duplicates found on the Destination Table

Comment: @samlexxy . . . You should ask that as a *new* question.